# sql server xquery shred attributes and nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery

I have an xml variable, I want to shred this input xml into relational table output as below

### input

```
  declare @x xml
  set @x =
  '<groupNodes>
        <groupSet name="groupset1" id="10001">
              <condition id="7">contains</contains>
              <group name="group11" id="11">100</group>
              <group name="group12" id="19">460</group>
              <group name="group13" id="24">450</group>
              <group name="group14" id="23">440</group>
        </groupSet>
        <groupSet name="groupset2" id="10002">
              <condition id="3">equals</contains>
              <group name="group21" id="21">370</group>
              <group name="group22" id="27">543</group>
        </groupSet>
        <groupSet name="groupset3" id="10003">
              <condition id="7">contains</contains>
              <group name="group31" id="31">760</group>
              <group name="group32" id="38">450</group>
              <group name="group33" id="39">420</group>
               ..
               ..
        </groupSet>
        ..
  </groupNodes>'
```

output

```
groupSetName      groupSetId   groupName      groupId            groupValue conditionId
-------------      ------------ --------------------------------------
groupset1            1001      group11            11            100          7
groupset1            1001      group12            19            460          7
groupset1            1001      group13            24            450          3
groupset1            1001      group14            23            440          3 
groupset2            1002      group21            21            370          3
groupset2            1002      group22            27            543          3
groupset3            1003      group31            31            760          7
groupset3            1003      group32            38            450          7
groupset3            1003      group33            39            420          7
```

I am trying something below, it  is giving only first row of each child node, not all of them are coming.Also, able to do groupset and group columns. not able to do condition node.

```
  select 
        tab.col.value('(@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') groupSetName,
        tab.col.value('(@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') groupSetId,
        tab.col.value('(./group/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') groupId,
        tab.col.value('(./group/@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') groupName,
        tab.col.value('(./group)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') groupValue
  from @x.nodes('groupNodes/groupSet') as tab(col)
```

Can some one please help me. I am trying very hard and couldn;t figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
select   
    tab.col.value('../@id', 'nvarchar(100)') groupsetName,  
    tab.col.value('../@name', 'nvarchar(100)') groupsetId,  
    tab.col.value('@id', 'nvarchar(100)') groupname,  
    tab.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') groupID,  
    tab.col.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') groupValue,
    tab.col.value('(../condition/@id)[1]','int')  
from @x.nodes('groupNodes/groupSet/group') as tab(col)
```

Comment: @sqlwxyz That's because you've **changed the question** and made it invalid xml.